# Add pseudo class to nth-child with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I want to use hover so that the bottom border on odd divs is a different color from `#75dcff`. However, `.card:hover div:nth-child(odd)` does not work. Can I apply psuedo classes to nth-child elements?

```css
.card {
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px 40px 40px;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.card:hover {
  border-color: #75dcff;
}

.card:hover div:nth-child(odd) {
  border-color: #ff7c5e;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `.card:nth-child(odd):hover`? **Edit**: See [@chazsolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48084471/2311559) :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect. `.card:hover div:nth-child(odd)` is selecting odd-indexed divs that are decendants of a `.card`, but your structure suggests that these should be the same thing. Adjust your selector to match the odd elements on hover:

```css
.card {
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px 40px 40px;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.card:hover {
  border-color: #75dcff;
}

.card:nth-child(odd):hover {
  border-color: #ff7c5e;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
```