# Can't get nth-child to work with bootstrap to change border color on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to grab the correct divs. I want to grab (even) divs and change the border color on hover. I am using the same card divs on another page without bootstrap and I can grab them just fine using .card:nth-child(even):hover

```
<style>
.card {
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 20px 40px 40px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 18px #888888;
  transition: .5s;
}
.card:hover {
  border-color: #75dcff;
}

.card:nth-child(even):hover {
  border-color: #ff7c5e;
}

.projects:nth-child(even):hover {
  border-color: #ff7c5e;
}

</style>
```

Using the css on .projects doesn't work. But when I remove the bootstrap fluff I can use .card:nth-child(even):hover to grab every other div with class="card"

```
<div class="container">


  <main class="flex">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-sm">
        <div class="card projects">
          <h2 class="card-title">VeVe</h2>
          <a href="https://veve.herokuapp.com" target="_blank">
            <img class="card-image" src="assets/images/veve.png">
          </a>
          <a class="card-github" href="#">Check out my code</a>
        </div>
      </div> 

       <div class="col-6 col-sm">
        <div class="card projects">
          <h2 class="card-title">H<sub>2</sub>Go</h2>
          <a href="http://h2go.today" target="_blank">
            <img class="card-image" src="assets/images/h2go.png">
          </a>
          <a class="card-github" href="#">Check out my code</a>
        </div>
       </div> 

       <div class="w-100"></div>

      <div class="col-6 col-sm"> 
       <div class="card projects">
         <h2 class="card-title">Trivia Game</h2>
         <a href="https://superberny.github.io/TriviaGame/">
           <img class="card-image" src="assets/images/triviagame.png">
         </a>
         <a class="card-github" href="#">Check out my code</a>
       </div>
      </div> 

      <div class="col-6 col-sm"> 
       <div class="card projects">
         <h2 class="card-title">Drumset</h2>
         <a href="https://superberny.github.io/Drumset/">
           <img class="card-image" src="assets/images/drumset.png">
         </a>
         <a class="card-github" href="#">Check out my code</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div> 

    </div>
```

Comment: CSS doesn't let you get every other *of a type*. (currently, it's proposed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

Comment: Why is it that when I use :nth-child(even) without bootstrap I can select even divs? The question is simple what element or class do I need to select? Here is my question from earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084421/add-pseudo-class-to-nth-child-with-css

Comment: Because you're not also selecting it by a class. See the linked thread above.

Comment: Ok I've gotta know, how is .card:nth-child(even):hover {
  border-color: #ff7c5e;
} not selecting a class?

Comment: `:nth-child` works on a group of siblings. In your case, `.card` are not siblings, they are separated by an ancestor `.col-6 .col-sm`. The thread shared by @jhpratt well explain it.

You should use an extra class on each even `.card`, as modifier, to define an other color. It should be the easier way.